# How do you ignore whitespace when using git whatchanged -p?

Tags: git

I can use

```
git whatchanged -p
```

to show a log of all the changes I've made to a repository with diffs inline.

I can use

```
git diff -b
```

or

```
git diff -w
```

to show a single diff that ignores various amounts of whitespace changes.

How can I pass that option to whatchanged in order to print out a list of changes I've made to my repository with inline diffs which ignores whitespace changes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about using `git log -p -w`?  I believe that is the same output as `whatchanged -p`.

Comment: That does give the same output as whatchanged.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to support the -w option either.

Comment: I take that back.  It turns out something that I thought was only a whitespace change was actually a real change.  `whatchanged -p -w` actually worked the way I expected it to.